# NullReferenceException when trying to add to a list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, oop, list, dictionary

When executing this code, I get a NullReferenceException on these lines:

```
List<Dictionary<Slot, string>> slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
                Dictionary<Slot, string> somedict = new Dictionary<Slot, string>();
                somedict.Add(new Slot(), "s");
                this.slots.Add(somedict);
```

I cant figure out what is going on. I created a dict with the right items, but when I try to add it to the list, I just get a NullReferenceException....

I've been looking around MSDN and this website for about 2 hours, but no luck. Can anyone help me out? I'm just trying to store a Dictionary, into a list.

```
namespace hashtable
{
    class Slot
    {
        string key;
        string value;

        public Slot()
        {
            this.key = null;
            this.value = null;
        }
    }

    class Bucket
    {
        public int count;
        public int overflow;
        public List<Dictionary<Slot, string>> slots;
        Dictionary<Slot, string> somedict;

        public Bucket()
        {
            this.count = 0;
            this.overflow = -1;
            List<Dictionary<Slot, string>> slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
            Dictionary<Slot, string> somedict = new Dictionary<Slot, string>();
            somedict.Add(new Slot(), "s");
            this.slots.Add(somedict);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Bucket` constructor is creating a local variable `slots` but you are trying to add  `somedict` to the (uninitialized) `Bucket` member `slots`.

Replace

```
List<Dictionary<Slot, string>> slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
```

with

```
this.slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
```

(which is the same as)

```
slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
```

You will have the same issue with `somedict`. If you do not mean it to be a class member in `Bucket`, do not declare it there. If you do, do not declare it as a local variable in the `Bucket` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I "know" what a NullReference means, just didn't remember the proper C# syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you use the more compact syntax of declaring local variables with `var` the problem is obvious...

```
var slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
var somedict = new Dictionary<Slot, string>();
somedict.Add(new Slot(), "s");
this.slots.Add(somedict);
```

As DocMax pointed out, you haven't initialized `this.slots` and probably meant...

```
this.slots = new List<Dictionary<Slot, string>>();
var somedict = new Dictionary<Slot, string>();
somedict.Add(new Slot(), "s");
this.slots.Add(somedict);
```

I suspect the declaration of the `Bucket.somedict` field is probably redundant as you are creating a local `somedict` and then adding it to the list where it can be retrieved later.